# jquery go back a directory

Tags: php, jquery, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a site that will allow me to use the new contenteditable function in HTML5, it all works perfectly however if I put the jquery file in a folder structure js/js.js and have my php save.php one directory back this does not work.

```
$("#save").click(function (e) {         
        var content = $('#editable').html();    

        $.ajax({
            url: '../save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            content: content
            },              
            success:function (data) {

                if (data == '1')
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("success")
                    .html("Data saved successfully")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("error")
                    .html("An error occured, the data could not be saved")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
            }
        });   

    });
```

Am I using the url parameter incorrectly?

please note all i have done is move my jquery file into a different folder and tried to go back one directory to the save.php file.

Comment: What matters is where is save.php in relation to the file rendering this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you write the urls in the script according to your `JavaScript`/`jQuery` file location.

You need to write the urls according to the script they get loaded into's file location.

#### Example

So if we say that this is your files.

- /js/script.js
- /save.php
- /index.php

Then the `index.php` loads the `/js/script.js` thereby the urls inside the scipt need to be according to the `index.php` file path.

Comment: Thanks for that, will remember for future reference!

Answer (score 1):

The ajax url is relative to the document that loaded the js not to the js file itself.